# What happens to a LinkedList node after I remove it?

Tags: java, linked-list

Typically, my go-to for removing a (singly) LinkedList node is to simply do:

```
Node.next = Node.next.next;
```

I'm wondering what happens to the Node that was removed? Since it did contain some allocated memory, will it cause a memory leak, and should it be freed somehow? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: It goes to the farm upstate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about freeing the memory of the node since Java takes cares of this for you.